# Table rates not working in backend Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, backend, bug, table-rates

When editing an existing order or create a new one in the backend of Magento I'm getting the following notification when trying to select a shipping method:

**Sorry, no quotes are available for this order.**

All fields have been filled correctly. The only shipping method that is activated on this Magento installation is the table rates method. If I enable the flat method it will not give the above notification and shows only the flat shipping option. Since there are multiple shipping prices used in this Magento installation I cannot use the latter.

The strange part about it is that the frontend works absolutely fine with the table rates method and orders are being placed daily.

Since I cannot see any strange things in the MySQL table and Magento is not outputting any errors in the logs or any javascript errors in the browser I'm kinda lost in finding the solution to this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if more information is needed I'm glad to share it.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer following Sites to Configuration Table Rates Shipping Method

**https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html**

**https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-table-rates-shipping-method-magento-2.html**

[image]

Any Query let me know...

Comment: Thanks for the tip............